# Is a text file in Java a GUI

Tags: java, file, user-interface

Is it right to think that when you create a text file in Java, you are essentially creating a text file like the one that appears with programs like notepad?

I have a JComboBox menu with various selections. I also created a text file and had it so that the user selection will be written in the text file. So the question is, how can I have this text file that I've created to appear? (as a GUI or any other way...)

My Code:

```
  static JFrame frame;
FileWriter f;
BufferedWriter bw;
int myAge;
String myStringAge;
 for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
            ageList.add(i);
        }

        DefaultComboBoxModel modelAge = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        for (Integer i : ageList) {
            modelAge.addElement(i);
        }

        JComboBox ageEntries = new JComboBox();
        ageEntries.setModel(modelAge);

        //Add ItemListener
        ageEntries.addItemListener(new ageListener());

   class ageListener implements ItemListener {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
        myAge = (Integer) event.getItem();
        myStringAge = Integer.toString(myAge);

        try {
            bw.write(myStringAge);
            bw.close();
        } catch (Exception e){

        }

    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  Don't ignore exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

A text file is not a GUI. Use JTextArea to display text.  Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using JEditorPane. You might want to create a new JFrame for it. Don't forget to `setContentType()` to "text/plain". Then you can just create a FileReader for your file and pass it to the editor pane throught the `read()` method.

Comment: Can you explain a little further? I am new to Java so it is still not very clear for me.

Comment: I can point you to this excellent tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html

Answer (score 0):

Start with [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).  That should answer your question (and the next 9).